# Nginx Test Successful but I cant Restart

Tags: nginx

```
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "lolnews.com.br" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "lolnews.com.br" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
root@lolnews2:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# service nginx restart
 * Restarting nginx nginx
```

Why this?

Comment: A few more Information would be useful
Did you test with `nginx -t` ? Whats the output of `service nginx status` after restart? Did you look in the log files?

Comment: seems that you have some proess listening on port 80 , provide output of `netstat -tlnp | grep 80`

Comment: root@lolnews2:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# netstat -tlnp | grep 80
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5025/nginx: worker

Comment: You have already nginx process listening on it

Comment: Yes.. my nginx is running, im trying to restart the service... but i cant :(

Comment: root@lolnews2:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# service nginx restart
 * Restarting nginx nginx                                                [fail]
root@lolnews2:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled#

Comment: kill that pid `kill -9 5025` and try restarting

Comment: root@lolnews2:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# kill -9 5025
root@lolnews2:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# service nginx restart                    * Restarting nginx nginx                                                [fail]
root@lolnews2:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled#

Comment: root@lolnews2:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# service nginx status
 * nginx is not running

Comment: root@lolnews2:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# service nginx status
 * nginx is not running

Comment: Check your logs and I still suspect something is still listening on port 80

Comment: Try:
service nginx stop && service nginx status

When it is still running you maybe have a problem with the pid file

Comment: @PratapSingh Killing a worker process doesn't stop the _master_ nginx process - that won't do anything. Eric - you need to stop/kill the master process. Note that you should probably be re _load_ ing nginx, not restarting.

Comment: @EricTeixeira with the message "Nginx is not running" when know it _is_ running means: only that `service nginx` doesn't know the pid of the running process.

Answer (score 0):

- Stop Nginx
- Check if nginx is still running:

  `ps faux | grep nginx`
- If nginx is running after the stop, kill the PID
- Check if some other process is using port 80 (or another port you're using in nginx)

  `netstat -tlnp | grep 80`

  `lsof -i :80`
- If there is another process/service using port 80, you can stop it if not needed
- Start nginx (only start not restart) , if error persist please check the log: /var/log/nginx/error.log (default location)